# Will changing the stator help sustain electrical accessories?

Tags: battery, stator

I have music on my motorcycle and LED lights. I find myself charging my battery a lot. So do I need to change the stator or alternator to help hold the power for my accessories or the regulator?

Comment: How long are you running the bike for - if it is only short trips it won’t have chance to re-charge the battery.

Comment: It would be helpful to know more about your motorcycle in order to give an accurate answer. Otherwise, you will just get general comments and guesses as answers.

Comment: Right! Honda Shadow Aero 2007 VT750. I do short and long trips.

Answer (score 1):

Check how much amps the alternator can deliver, and make an estimation of the amps you'll consume. There must still be a margin for safety.

What audio system and LED bulbs do you have? Normal LED lights consume less than halogen light(approx. 30W per bulb), and a standard radio does rarely consume more than 50W. Little enough for an alternator to power. If you find yourself charging the battery a lot, you could also have a faulty voltage regulator or battery.

Check for the voltage with a DMM when you're running all your accessories. Rev up the engine to cruise rpm to get a realistic situation. The voltage must not drop below ~13V on a full battery. It's not allowed to exceed 14.4V either. If your voltages are right while all the accessories are running, the alternator is likely not at fault.

If you're determined to increase alternator output for any reason, fitting a stronger/bigger one is often easier than tweaking the current one. And also more reliable.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies...Checking it all out now!